# Models File in Php is Corrupted How to recover it show in Hexa Decimal

Tags: git

I don't know about this problem I have faced this type of problem for the first time as me and my friend is been developing a project. and for the version controlling we use GIT.
Yesterday when we merged code we faced this problem that some of our Models file code is not there and only see the **ZEROS**

Here is the picture[image]

Comment: check git changes and revert it back. then re-merge single file to double check what causing this issue.

Comment: i have revert it back to the Last commit then again we merge it into another branch but still its causing, is there anything that convert back it. i can go forward and backward and then commit but thats very hectic

Comment: merged with GIT? i've never had this issue, i think this could be some problem with file previously. try deleting the previous file add again and then merge.

Comment: Similar we have pushed it to another branch

Comment: try remove old then creating a new file put the code in it add into git and then check. its just kind of guessing since there is no issue reported in this regard

Comment: Ok, Give me 5 mints then

Comment: @Noman it works !!! well what I really did we both move to the last commits, then I switched to the new branch and pushed that branch into Git hub and then my friend has a pull he merged the code then he pushed the code into the same branch. and now its perfectly fine, but i don't know why this error pop up and what exactly its solution is..

Comment: glad you made it work. but its kinda weird issue to me :D i don't know what was the reason we all can guess only. might be some virus or misleading content type.

Comment: yes thanx for helping me out